# Correlated subquery returning value - 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, correlated-subquery, lead

I have a calendar table which allows me to count business days.  The most basic query I run goes like this:

```
SELECT SUM(calD.busDay) [Sum Of Days]
FROM [dbo].[CalendarDays] calD 
WHERE calD.calDay BETWEEN '1/1/2016' AND '1/3/2016'
```

Since New Year's Day isn't a business day (for us) but the 2nd and 3rd days are, then `[Sum Of Days] = 2`.

However, when I put this into a correlated subquery such as this, the output is not as consistent:

```
SELECT c2.*,
    (SELECT SUM(calD.busDay) [Sum Of Days]
    FROM [dbo].[CalendarDays] calD 
    WHERE calD.calDay BETWEEN c2.[thisDate] AND c2.[Next Date]) [Days In Step]
FROM
    (SELECT c.*,
        CASE WHEN LEAD(c.[ID], 1) OVER (ORDER BY c.[ID], c.[thisDate]) = c.[ID]
            THEN LEAD(c.[thisDate], 1) OVER (ORDER BY c.[ID], c.[thisDate])
            ELSE NULL END [Next Date]
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Test] c ) c2
```

Here are my results with a small data set:

[image: test data]

Row 7 stands out.  It says 173 days elapsed between the two dates, but when I run the query Select for the explicit days I get 174 days.  Row 8 is also strange, clearly there are two dates there but it comes back as NULL.

I really don't understand what's happening here.

Comment: It looks like you are using a datetime fields, maybe use the convert function to remove the time parts.

Comment: That works.  I wonder why the query handles the time parts when plugged in explicitly.

Comment: row 8: if your calendar table has `2015-06-22 00:00:00` then this will not fall between `2015-06-22 15:09:00` and `2015-06-22 15:48:00`

Comment: I think you're right.  Chuck's suggestion worked, I removed the time parts using CONVERT() and all is well.  What is not clear to me is when I input the datetime as a string it returns the desired number.  Perhaps strings are converted implicitly?